# asp.net mvc 4 minifies css media queries in wrong way

Tags: css, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4, media-queries, bundling-and-minification

i am using ASP.NET MVC 4 version and Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization '1.1.2' 
after minifing this media query:

```
@media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1599px) {
    #circles_inner {
        width: 1080px;
        margin: auto;
    }
}
```

i get this css:

```
@media(min-width:1025px)and (max-width:1599px){#circles_inner{width:1080px;margin:auto}}
```

the space is omitted before

> and

tag, the new chrome version on mac doesn't understand it.

This is actually a viable update for Google Chrome. It is just being more strict on the syntax of media queries. A solution for MVC projects can be found here: http://i-skool.co.uk/net/mvc/mvc-bundling-and-minifcation-issues-with-google-chrome/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it looks like a bug report for the makers of the software